# Issue when running script in *.bat files on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have the following script in a *.bat file.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Backup database
ECHO %date%%time%
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\OSQL.EXE" -S 127.0.0.1 -U accellos -P accellos -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [BCS_DC] TO  DISK = N'E:\backups\BCS_DC.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'BCS_DC full backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10" -o "E:\backups\report_BCS_DC.out"
ECHO Compressing...
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a "E:\backups\BCS_DC.rar" -o+ "E:\backups\BCS_DC.bak"
IF NOT EXIST E:\backups\BCS_DC.rar GOTO END
ECHO Deleting obsolete file
del E:\backups\BCS_DC.bak
for /f "tokens=1-9 delims=.: " %d in ("%date%%time%") do ren E:\backups\BCS_DC.rar BCS_DC_%e_%f_%g_%i_%j.rar
ECHO Done.
:END
sleep 20
```

The script is run by a scheduled task daily and has to make a backup of a given DB, then compress it with WinRAR and after that - rename the file to match the current date.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work fine on Windows Server 2008. It works as a charm on Server 2003, but on 2008 it skips the file rename as the command row is missing.

I have another *.bat file on this machine which doesn't work but works well on 2003. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try stackoverflow's sister site, serverfault.

Comment: If you right-click on the batch file in Windows Explorer, make a shortcut, then right-click on that shortcut and click Properties => Advanced, then click the Compatibility tab and tell it to be run as Windows 2003, does it work then? If so that might be a decent if hackish workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: **Task Scheduler** go to "Actions" then "Edit" then fill in the "Start in (Optional):" field with the path of your ".Bat" file.